# Cloud bucket virus security

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I have implemented an antivirus system using ClamAV on one of my apps which uses Google cloud storage for uploading files.
Currently what I am doing is, listening to bucket upload, download it on one of my servers, scan it using ClamAV, and deleting it if it was infected.

I am a newbie to this, **Is it possible that the whole cloud bucket gets infected by a virus on upload only.
i.e, can a virus execute himself on the bucket(any cloud bucket) itself?**

If yes then please suggest some other solution to solve this issue as my current solution would be ineffective in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object Storage systems do not provide an execution framework hence an infected file cannot infect other files in the bucket.